# 切れかけの蛍光灯とは何ですか？とくに切れかけ？

Tags: words

> 切れかけの蛍光灯。

What does the above mean? What is 切れかけ?

Comment: https://blog.goo.ne.jp/h-shiohama/e/bd76cc9c42d25ee7151bc9859754af45